# identifier "KeyboardController" is undefined

Tags: c++, oop, interface

**Edit: Solved!** Using the suggestions by πάντα ῥεῖ and molbdnilo I put the class definition inside the header file and declared my object as a pointer. I also dereferenced the pointer via "kc->move(text)" at the bottom of main.cpp. I also ended up passing text as a reference so that any changes the controller made to it would stick with it when the window was updated farther down main.cpp.
**/Edit**

I am attempting to create a simple rogue-like game in VS2010 using C++. At the same time I want to incorporate OOP concepts that I am learning at the same time(self learning using multiple internet sources).

The concept I am having trouble with is implementing Interfacing(which I have read isn't really a c++ thing but that it is possible to do anyway). My thoughts are to create an interface for controllers where KeyboardController IS A controller and GamepadController(coming soon!) IS A controller.

In main.cpp I included the header file for my controller interface(abstract class?). I also attempted a declaration using "KeyboardController kc;" which err's that KeyboardController is undefined. I then attempted "MyController kc = new KeyboardController();" based on searching through other's issues and blindly trying their fixes with no good results (I also didn't think this would work because MyController is not supposed to be concrete and the error I got confirmed this).

As I hinted at above, I have read tens of "identifier 'X' is undefined" posts but most of the issues appear to be from improper(unguarded or redundant) includes.

The following is the code I decided to leave it at before I run out of hair.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "mycontroller.h"

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML works!");
    // declaring my class
    MyController kc = new KeyboardController();
    // KeyboardController kc;

    sf::Text text, hud;
    sf::Font font;
    if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf"))
    {
        // error...
    }

    text.setFont(font);
    hud.setFont(font);
    text.setString("X");
    hud.setString("You wake up in a black void.");
    text.setCharacterSize(12);
    text.setColor(sf::Color::White);
    text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
    text.setPosition(400, 300);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // check the type of the event...
            switch (event.type)
            {
                // window closed
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;

                // key pressed
                case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                   kc.move(text); // using method from my declared class
...
```

**mycontroller.h** (I have commented out the KeyboardController here because I believe it goes in the next file .cpp and also the constructor)

```
#ifndef MyController_H
#define MyController_H
/* This header file is to create an interface for my controllers */

class MyController {
    public:
       // MyController(){}
        virtual ~MyController(){}
        virtual void move(sf::Text player) = 0;
};

/*
class KeyboardController : public MyController{
    public:
      //  KeyboardController(){}
       ~KeyboardController()
        virtual void move(sf::Text player);
};
*/
#endif
```

**mycontroller.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "mycontroller.h"
/* This file is where I intend to instantiate my concrete controllers */

class KeyboardController : public MyController{
    public:
       // KeyboardController();
       ~KeyboardController();
        virtual void move(sf::Text player);
};

/*
KeyboardController::KeyboardController()
{
}
*/

KeyboardController::~KeyboardController()
{
}

void KeyboardController::move(sf::Text player)
{
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
            {
                player.move(-4, 0);
            }
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't create a `KeyboardController` in `main` unless it's known there. The class definition needs to be in the header, not in the implementation file.

Comment: This _"MyController kc"_ must be changed to `MyController* kc`.

Comment: Thank you both! I put the definition back in the header and added what I believe is the pointer(Mycontroller* kc). I also dereferenced the pointer using "kc->move" instead of "kc.move" at the bottom of main.cpp. At least that is what I think it's called, I am not strong in pointers yet. Everything is working now!